# Excel VBA help copying rows based on values in row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a number of rows starting at row B which give details of projects.

E.g.

```
ProjectID, END Date, Number of Hours to complete, Number of Weeks to complete 
AAA001, 15-Jan-2017, 37.5, 4 
AAB002, 15-Feb-2017, 75, 5 
AAC003, 20-Feb-2017, 37.5, 3
```

I would like each row to be copied into a new sheet a number of times (based on the number of weeks to complete), I would like the number of hours to complete to be divided by the number of weeks to complete, and I would like to Date to go back a number of weeks based on the number of weeks to complete 
e.g.

```
AAA001, 18-Dec-16, 9.375, 1 
AAA001, 25-Dec-16, 9.375, 1 
AAA001, 1-Jan-17, 9.375, 1 
AAA001, 8-Jan-17, 9.375,1 
AAB002, 11-Jan-17, 15, 1 
AAB002, 18-Jan-17, 15 ,1 
AAB002, 25-Jan-17, 15 ,1 
AAB002, 1-Feb-17, 15 ,1 
AAB002, 15-Feb-17, 15, 1 
...
```

and so on

is there a way to do this in VBA, and then to sort the resulting table in order based on date?

I am afraid I have tried to look for solutions and can only find part answers. It would help me a lot if someone could comment the code they provide.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Yes. Of course I meant row 2.  Thank you shash678.  And thank you to the person who edited my question to make it look nice

Comment: This is not a for free development. SO is help for developers. Show us your code and where you have an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not optimized, but works. I hope it makes what you meant. Yout input must be on the first sheet from column A to D, and you need to have a second sheet

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Double
    i = 2
    k = 2
    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value
    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 3).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3).Value
    Sheets(2).Cells(1, 4).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4).Value
    While Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        cnt = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value
        For j = 1 To cnt
            Sheets(2).Cells(k, 1).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
            Sheets(2).Cells(k, 2).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
            Sheets(2).Cells(k, 3).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value / Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value
            Sheets(2).Cells(k, 4).Value = 1
            k = k + 1
        Next j
        i = i + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you tretom. I wanted the date to change too, but I am hoping that this is a good starting point and I can perhaps try and work out how to do that myself.

I am sorry, I am not a developer, I have just been asked to try and do this in VBA/Excel, which is something I am not too familiar with.

Comment: oh, sorry, you just have to make in the for loop something like `Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value - (Sheets(1).Cells(1, 4).Value - j)*7` (I haven't tested it)